# static class allocation

Tags: c#, class, static

In C# are static classes stack allocated?

Since they cannot be instantiated, I guess that must the how it is done.

Comment: If/because they're not instantiated, then no instances of them are allocated.

Comment: Why would you allocate something on the temporary store that is *not temporary*? The stack, aka the temporary store, is for allocating things that *go away*. But static classes never go away.

Comment: @ChrisW: Then where do the static fields of the static class live?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're stored inside the area of the heap called the *High Frequency Heap*. You can find more details in this codeproject article. [Static Keyword Demystified](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/codeconcepts.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that static classes are allocated on the heap (using the static constructor, when the type is initialised).

If they were on the stack, you'd run out of stack space very quickly, if you had a lot of static classes kicking around.